# Python и firebase

Tags: python, firebase

Есть элементарный код:

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://my_super_private_project.firebaseio.com', None)
test = "Stop"

result = firebase.post('/engine', test)
print (result)
```

Работает отлично, но в firebase приходит такое:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vcKD.jpg

Ну и print выдаёт такое:

```
{'name': '-L7fBjEexKyoryVjNVeB'}
```

Можно ли как-то отправить "чистые" данные? Без "-L7fBjEexKyoryVjNVeB"?

Грубо говоря, чтобы просто "engine: Stop"

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно, метод `post` создаёт новый дочерний элемент `engine` и возвращает вам его идентификатор. На сколько я понимаю, вам нужно не создать дочерний элемент, а изменить значение самого `engine`. Если так, то используйте `put` вместо `post`:

```
result = firebase.post('/', 'engine', 'test')
```